# How does one utilize qfx and ofx files in GNUCash?

Tags: gnucash

I currently use Quicken to manage my personal finances.  I'm a little irked because it does not have an SQL interface (unless you want to shell out the cash for an ODBC driver, which I do not).

The main reason I use it, is for the bank syncing feature; I'm not wild about the tagging and categorization feature in Quicken.  Other than that it's proprietary.

I [read](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Announcement_2.2.0#Playing_With_Others) that it's possible to sync with your bank using GNU Cash; the institutions that I use, use `QFX` and `OFX` Web connect, so I should be able to use them with GNU cash; but I'm not sure how (especially in the case of OFX web connect) as Quicken has some sort of a search that it does to connect via web connect.

Can someone offer me some insight into the process?